# Disable component editing in CQ/AEM

Tags: aem, sling

I've got a variety of situations where I have a component A which uses cq:include to include component B. Both A and B are editable and have dialogs. However, when B is included in A, I'd like to disable direct editing of component B - I'll manage the authoring through A's dialog. I've seen a couple methods that accomplish this. The first is

```
<% IncludeOptions.getOptions(request, true).forceSameContext(true); %>
```

and the second is

```
<% slingRequest.setAttribute(ComponentContext.BYPASS_COMPONENT_HANDLING_ON_INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTE, true); %>
<% slingRequest.removeAttribute(ComponentContext.BYPASS_COMPONENT_HANDLING_ON_INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTE);  %>
```

My understanding is that the first forces the child component into the parent's editing context, and the second just creates no editing context for the child at all. But I'm not sure what the difference really means. As far as I can tell, the only major difference is that the first one only affects the next component include, while the second one affects all includes between the two lines. There's also a minor difference in the markup generated. But beyond that, the dialogs seem to behave the same way. It's possible that my POC is just too simple to see the differences...are there values in a cq:EditConfig node that would be affected? Some other difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also just swtich off edit mode for an include with the WCMMode:

```
<%WCMMode prevMode = WCMMode.DISABLED.toRequest(request);%>
    <cq:include path="b" resourceType="B" />
<%prevMode.toRequest(request);%>
```

This will render B like it would be rendered on a publish server without any edit functionality.